# Cannot Start Debugging in MonoDevelop

Tags: linux, linux-mint, debug, monodevelop

The option for Debugging is greyed out.

I'm running MonoDevelop 7.8.2 (build 2) on Linux Mint 19.1
My project is a .NET Core 2.0 project.
All debugging related add-ins are enabled, yet this option is still greyed out.

Any help on this would be great, I'm a relatively new (couple of months) Linux user, Visual Studio is the last thing I needed a replacement of, with MonoDevelop being everything I need it to be. Except for this problem where I can't seem to debug.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Facing the same issue in MonoDevelop 7.8.4 (build 2), Ubuntu 18.04. Does anybody know?